How to sort python pandas dataframe in repetitive order after groupby?
I have a dataset which is sorted in this order:



col1
col2
col3




a
1
r


a
1
s


a
2
t


a
2
u


a
3
v


a
3
w


b
4
x


b
4
y


b
5
z


b
5
q


b
6
w


b
6
e



I want it to be sorted in the following order:



col1
col2
col3




a
1
r


a
2
t


a
3
v


a
1
s


a
2
u


a
3
w


b
4
x


b
5
z


b
6
w


b
4
y


b
5
q


b
6
e



I want the col2 to be in repetitive fashion, as in, for col1 'a' values, it should be 1,2,3,4 and then 1,2,3,4 again instead of 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4.
I have used the following code, but it is not working:
import pandas as pd

# Creating the DataFrame
data = {
    'col1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    'col2': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6],
    'col3': ['r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 'e']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Sort by col1, then reorder col2 within each group
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']).reset_index(drop=True)

df_sorted = df_sorted.groupby('col1', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('col2'))

# Display the sorted dataframe
print(df_sorted)



Can you explain what the order actually is? It's hard to understand from the table.

I want the col2 to be in repetitive fashion, as in, for col1 'a' values, it should be 1,2,3,4 and then 1,2,3,4 again instead of 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4. Does this help?

Use groupby.cumcount to form a secondary key for sorting:
out = (df.assign(key=lambda x: x.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).cumcount())
         .sort_values(by=['col1', 'key', 'col2'])
         .drop(columns='key')
      )

Note that you can avoid creating the intermediate column using numpy.lexsort:
import numpy as np

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([df['col2'],
                          df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).cumcount(),
                          df['col1']])]

Output:
   col1  col2 col3
0     a     1    r
2     a     2    t
4     a     3    v
1     a     1    s
3     a     2    u
5     a     3    w
6     b     4    x
8     b     5    z
10    b     6    w
7     b     4    y
9     b     5    q
11    b     6    e

Intermediate (before sorting):
   col1  col2 col3  key
0     a     1    r    0
1     a     1    s    1
2     a     2    t    0
3     a     2    u    1
4     a     3    v    0
5     a     3    w    1
6     b     4    x    0
7     b     4    y    1
8     b     5    z    0
9     b     5    q    1
10    b     6    w    0
11    b     6    e    1

